# Why does Google Analytic request a GIF file?

Tags: google-analytics

Why does Google Analytic request a GIF file?

Is it because the GIF allows access to more data than JavaScript alone. Is it to get the IP address of the user?

Comment: @Chacha102: the Analytics JavaScript makes a request to a GIF image.

Comment: @Chacha102: Chechl google's page about the gif request strucuture. http://code.google.com/intl/en-US/apis/analytics/docs/tracking/gaTrackingTroubleshooting.html#gifParameters

Comment: FYI the GA request structure mentioned above moved [here](https://developers.google.com/analytics/resources/concepts/gaConceptsTrackingOverview#gifParameters)

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Even with JavaScript enabled, analytics requests a GIF file. If you look at the GET params of the image, it contains a lot of information about the browser. Stuff like `utmsr=1280x1024` (the screen size). Google Code has a [list of parameters](https://developers.google.com/analytics/resources/concepts/gaConceptsTrackingOverview?hl=en).

It uses the image request to send information about the browser without an `XMLHttpRequest`.

Now, to actually answer the original question, Google is probably doing this to get around [cross-domain `XMLHttpRequest`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/HTTP_access_control) restrictions.

Comment: I believe that Google uses an image request simply because they don't need to receive any information, only send. An image request is the most lightweight way to do this.

Comment: This answer is not giving anything useful. 
@mylesmg Your answer is the correct one.

Answer (score 22):

Google's javascript has to transmit the details of your page view to their servers some how. Ajax cannot be used across domains, so the only way to submit the information is to request a file from a Google server, passing the necessary information in the query string. To facilitate this, some form of content must be requested using a standard HTML tag. The easiest way to do this without impacting the page itself is to load a 1x1 transparent gif. Note that in the case of the Google script (and others), this image isn't actually added to the page. It's merely loaded via a javascript statement

```
var img1 = new Image();
img1.src = 'http://path/to/file.gif?otherinfohere';
```

This loads the image without adding it to the page. The information could also be loaded using a script tag like so:

```
<script src="http://path/to/script.js?otherinfohere" type="text/javascript"><script>
```

However, users are more likely to have javascript blocked than images, so the safer route is to request an image. As to why they would use a gif instead of say, a jpg, a gif is safer in case a rogue browser actually adds the image to the page. The transparent gif is unlikely to negatively impact the layout, where as a 1x1 jpg would leave a 1 pixel dot somewhere on the page.

Edit: To add to my comment about users having blocked javascript, a gif request containing static information can be added inside a noscript tag to allow basic tracking even in the event that javascript is disabled. To my knowledge, GA doesn't do this, but some other web analytics providers do.

Answer (score 16):

http://www.perlmonks.org/?node_id=7974

The smallest transparent GIF is **43 bytes**.

http://garethrees.org/2007/11/14/pngcrush/

The smallest transparent PNG-24 (which can't be shown by older browsers too) is **67 bytes**.

http://www.techsupportteam.org/forum/digital-imaging-photography/1892-worlds-smallest-valid-jpeg.html

The smallest (opaque) JPEG is **134 bytes**.

The math is simple! Bigger size = more costs.

Comment: **67** bytes, not 73 bytes. You have to read all the way to the end for the punchline!

Answer (score 1):

1. you can use the __utm.gif tracker without javascript (w some server help)
2. you can use it in an email message (w some programmatic help before sending the email)
3. Urchin was developed before AJAX was popular (2005)

It has nothing to do w cross-domain. They could have used JSONP for that.

Comment: JSONP is for getting data, and Google Analytics only needs to transmit data.

Comment: the image tag is for getting data, and OH WAIT. you can put querystring parameters in a JSONP request the same as for an image...and return a 204

Comment: I see this is trying to be ironic but I can't reach the genious