# Why do Web Analytics Applications Never Use JSONP

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, browser, web-analytics

I'm thinking of building an application for myself that is similar to Google Analytics, Getclicky, etc.

I've noticed that all of these websites use Image beacons to send data to the servers.

**Aside from the size overhead**, is there any reason to **not use** JSONP using jQuery?

Comment: Also see [Why does Google Analytic request a GIF file?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2083043/why-does-google-analytic-request-a-gif-file)

Comment: The point of JSON-P is to get data from a different origin … analytics scripts only *send* data.

Comment: Are there any browsers that don't support JSONP?

Comment: If you can load a script on a different server (such as using Google's CDN), your browser supports it (should have support since the dawn of web almost).

Answer (score 10, accepted):

JSONP is great when you want a response with meaningful data.  In the case of analytics you dont care about the result.  The easiest fastest and simplest way to send a GET request to a remote server is by requesting an image.  And if you don't care what the response is, then anything else is needless complexity.